# Disable Free Shipping After Discount?

Tags: magento-1, shopping-cart-price-rules, free-shipping

This is driving me crazy. How do I disable free shipping after someone enters a promotional/discount code? I want this to be an either/or scenario. They can't get the discount and free shipping!

Ok..I have enabled the "Free Shipping" method and set the minimum order amount to $75. I've also created a shopping cart price rule for the discount I want to offer with the following selections:

Conditions:
If ALL are TRUE: Subtotal is greater than $75.00

Actions:
Apply - Percent of Product....
Discount Amount - 0
Apply to Shipping - Yes
Free Shipping - For shipment with matching items
Stop Further Rules Processing - No

This priority rule is set to "2".

I've left the Conditions section as default and have selected the following options under "Actions":

Apply - Percent of product discount
Discount Amount - 15
Apply to Shipping Amount - No
Free Shipping - No
Stop Further Rules Processing - No

The priority for this rule is "1"

Finally, it might be worth noting that I'm still on version 1.4.1.1. Scary...I know.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm dying over here!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the option completely from one page checkout, you can do with code as below. might be  something like this should work:

```
<?php
$couponCode = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getCouponCode();
if(!$couponCode) {

      IF NO COUPON CODE FOUND
      FREE SHIPPING CODE GOES HERE AND WILL DISPLAY SHIPPING.

}
?>
```

hope this will sure work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using shopping cart price rule to discount your flat rate shipping method (or whatever method you're using) to 0.00? And make sure that you can't apply two shopping cart price rules.